# Need to write a batch file call a program in loop

Tags: batch-file

The program is a c# console app, unfortunately for some unknown reason, it keep failing out every hour or so, when it fails, it will display the stacktrace then exits.

While fixing the bug, is there a way to write a quick batch file that just calls this program when it errors out and terminate itself? This will ensure we can still have this program running all the times.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a BATCH file that will simply run your program over and over again.  Something like:

```
@echo off
:start
YourProgram.exe
goto start
```